# Compare two string and get the uncommon words strikeoff using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to compare both the string and get the uncommon result.
I have tried the below code which gives the output whether the result comparison is true or false.
I want to get the result of uncommon words in a variable.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    <h3>User 1</h3>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user1.name">
    Age: <input type="number" ng-model="user1.age">

    <h3>User 2</h3>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user2.name">
    Age: <input type="number" ng-model="user2.age">

    <div>
      <br/>
      <input type="button" value="Compare" ng-click="compare()">
    </div>
    User 1: <pre>{{user1 | json}}</pre>
    User 2: <pre>{{user2 | json}}</pre>
    Equal: <pre>{{result}}</pre>
    Uncommon words: <pre>{{compare}}</pre>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";

 $scope.user1 = {};
  $scope.user2 = {};
  $scope.result;

  $scope.compare = function() {
    $scope.result = angular.equals($scope.user1, $scope.user2);
  };

});
</script>
```

Could someone suggest me some idea to proceed with this ?

Comment: Plz add a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RoyasonSilva/3geavnqs/

Comment: explain with some example , for getting better understanding .